# What do you call it when a scam artist modifies the contents of a document to deceive other people?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, legalese

Some unscrupulous scam artist decided to modify a contract that had my signature on it, to make it appear that I had agreed to things I did not. Here is a simplified example:

> Bob agrees to pay Fred $20,000 for Fred’s service of building Bob a home.
>
> The bellow signature indicates acceptances into this contract.
>
> Bob’s Signature: *Bob*
>   Fred’s Signature: *Fred*

Now say Bob gets crafty and uses an image editing software, such as Photoshop, to replace "$20,000" with "$10,000".

What would this be called? What word would describe this "falsified" document? I'm not so much looking for a legally correct term, as what's legal is for the judge to decide. I'm looking for an easily understandable term. It looks like I'm going to have to explain this to a few people and I want a way to distinguish between two documents where one had been subtly altered.

Since both signatures are valid, I don’t think it’s correct to say it’s forged. I also considered fake, but not sure this is accurate as (in a sense) it is intended to be different from the original. Other words that come to mind are counterfeit and phony.

Comment: The document is forged; the signature is not forged.

Comment: Please provide a sentence where your word would fit. So far it's not clear whether you want a word for the act which was done on the document or a word naming the resulting document, or whether you want a noun or an adjective.

Comment: BTW, it's "acceptance of" the contract, not "acceptances into" the contract. And of course, "below" not "bellow."

Comment: The word 'forgery' is in no way limited to signatures. You can forge art, documents, contracts, etc. The word you are looking for is forgey.

Comment: @Shane “Where are we?”  “We're in a blacksmith's workshop.”  “Oh, I should've know:  this place had a certain ‘forgey’ look about it.”

Comment: It is definitely correct to say the document is forged. Forgery includes ANY alteration of a document for fraudulent purposes, not just signatures.

Comment: Is it just me or anyone else finds it weird that the one who **has** this document is the one who has to pay ? He could as well just destroy the paper and *woooh!* no amount is due. I would instead expect Fred to edit the document and replace `$20.000` with `$30.000` for example.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

To distinguish between the legitimate document and the one that was altered to be deceptive, you could refer to the falsified document as **doctored**.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/doctored) provides the definition under *doctor* as a transitive verb:

> **2.b.** to alter deceptively

The *OED* provides a more detailed definition:

> **3.** fig. To treat so as to alter the appearance, flavour, or character of; to disguise, falsify, tamper with, adulterate, sophisticate, ‘cook’.

A recent example from [*Wired*](https://www.wired.com/story/cyberattacks-against-abortion-clinics/) magazine uses the word to describe a video edited to be deceptive.

> In July 2015, Planned Parenthood’s website was hacked shortly after the Center for Medical Progress, an anti-abortion group, released secretly recorded (and discredited) videos **doctored** to make it seem like Planned Parenthood sold fetal tissue.

Comment: This is very descriptive though it does not indicate that the changes were made to commit fraud.  Most fashion  and many wedding photos are doctored in a marketing effort or in the name of vanity.

Comment: @KalleMP That's a fair point.  But when someone refers to a "doctored document" it's generally understood that it was edited maliciously.  It fits with the definition, "to alter *deceptively.*"  Even with photos, if someone says "edited" there is no negative connotation, but with "doctored" there is a sense that the resulting photos are misleading.  Having said that, all the answers here would work, the OP could really choose any of these words to get their point across.

Answer (score 31):

Traditionally, the word for both the faked document and the act of faking the document would be [***forgery***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/forgery). From Merriam-Webster:

> 2. : something forged
> 3. : an act of forging; *especially* : the crime of falsely and fraudulently making or altering a document (such as a check)

Your document has been fraudulently altered, so in your example

> This contract is a **forgery**. Bob engaged in **forgery** when he secretly altered the terms written on the contract after he and Fred had both signed it.

In the particular case that you've described, assuming you are correct that "an image editing software" was used to alter the contract, this is also a particularly egregious case of [***photoshopping***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/photoshop) (even if Adobe's product isn't used to create the fraudulent document). Also from M-W:

> **photoshop**
>   *verb, often capitalized*
>   transitive verb
>   : to alter (a digital image) with Photoshop software or other image-editing software especially in a way that distorts reality (as for deliberately deceptive purposes)

So Fred could say something like

> This isn't what I actually agreed to; the original contract that I signed has been **photoshopped**.

You could also combine the two terms, for greatest clarity:

> I signed a similar document, but this one is a **photoshopped forgery**.

---

<sub>ETA: I am not a lawyer; this answer is just about the common usage of the terms, not their legal application or implications ;-).</sub>

Comment: This was certainly what came to my mind.  I'm know the OP objected to this term specifically because both signatures were authentic, but "forgery" to me does not imply anything about the specific nature of the faking (i.e. whether the signatures or something else was altered)

Comment: This is definitely the correct term from a legal perspective as well. [Legal](http://dictionary.law.com/Default.aspx?selected=775) [definitions](http://criminal.findlaw.com/criminal-charges/forgery.html) [of forgery](http://thelawdictionary.org/forgery/) make it clear that forgery includes both creating false documents and altering real documents. Whether you create a document from scratch, add to or delete from an existing one, or alter the wording of a document, if the purpose is to deceive for gain, it's the crime of forgery.

Answer (score 27):

The document has been **falsified**

> to change something, such as a document, in order to deceive people

[Falsify](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/falsify)

> Falsifying documents is a type of white collar crime ....... etc

[Falsifying Documents](https://www.legalmatch.com/law-library/article/falsifying-documents.html)

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps **fraudulently altered** would convey the meaning you are trying to put across.

It would cover both the [motive to deceive](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/fraud) and the [act of modifying](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/alter?s=t) the document.

Many forged things are fair copies of the original where this is specifically not a direct copy.

The [Legal Information Institute](https://www.law.cornell.edu/ucc/3/3-407) writes **an alteration fraudulently made discharges a party whose obligation is affected by the alteration**, and in [A Digest of the Laws of the State of Georgia](https://books.google.fi/books?id=z10NAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA636&lpg=PA636&dq=fraudulently%20altered&source=bl&ots=Wtm8xShnSj&sig=GxL0A5WEUmZQZqSajAoz-zVvraE&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=fraudulently%20altered&f=false) and [Acts Passed by the General Assembly of Georgi](https://books.google.fi/books?id=igY4AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA169&lpg=PA169&dq=fraudulently%20altered&source=bl&ots=3V3YgiaBIo&sig=02rGe7InpIYWSSsCJuVZTD30qMs&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=fraudulently%20altered&f=false)a we read **If any person ... shall falsely and fraudulently alter ... note, ... such person ... shall ... be punished**

Comment: That's a good suggestion - would you mind providing definitions and a sample sentence, as we normally do for [tag:single-word-request] questions?  Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

"Altered," may be enough:

"The presentation of a forged or altered instrument is evidence, in and of itself, of an intent to defraud a bank." U.S. v. Laljie, 184 F.3d 180 (4th Cir. 1999).

Answer (score 5):

You may choose to use the word [Tampered](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/tamper) to define such documents.

In fact there is a popular digital signature service feature, called [Tamper Evidence](https://www.signix.com/digital-signature-tamper-evidence)

> *If someone tries to change any part of the document (even something as simple as deleting a space or capitalizing a word), there’s proof
>   that changes took place.*

Comment: I like the word but tampering does not imply fraud or malice.

Comment: Yes it does. Unauthorized alterations of any kind can be defined as tampering.

Comment: Tampering may be the result of curiosity when opening a radionic unit, self reliance when changing a iPhone battery or tidiness when despeckling up a scanned document.  None of these may have been authorised but all were tampering though no fraud was intended (though DMCA and other _right not to fix_ legislation can say otherwise) unless attempts to hide the act were also made.

Comment: The OP stated that `the contents of the documents were modified to deceive people`. Since the intent was to deceive people, that means fraud was committed.For example, this is how the Kentucky Govt. describes _tampering_ of documents - `Knowing he lacks the authority to do so, he intentionally destroys, mutilates,
conceals, removes, or otherwise impairs the availability of any public records` http://www.lrc.ky.gov/Statutes/statute.aspx?id=19864